# Remote access to Google Colab hardware

Tags: gpu, google-colaboratory, virtualization

Is it possible to use Google Colab GPU, from my local storage and local system?  As far as I know, programs such as Juice-Labs or Nvidia vGPU provide detailed capabilities, but is it possible to use them in Google Colab?

I tried to run Juice-Labs in Google Colab, but it requires opening ports for it to work, and this is not possible in Google Colab